# How to start KDE "Display and Monitor" directly

Tags: 16.04, kubuntu, multiple-monitors

Using Kubuntu 16.04, I haven't found a way to get to the "Display and Monitor" settings without first going to "System Settings" and then click the display and monitor icon. This annoys be, because I would rather like to have an icon or tray setting (like the old krandrtray) to easily switch monitor configurations.

Is there a way to get to the "Display and Monitor" dialog directly -- via the command line, or some widget?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think the what you are looking for is the command

`kcmshell5 kcm_kscreen`

On a sidenote, to find out which modules you can start with kcmshell5, use `kcmshell5 --list`

Personally, I think the easiest way is, to activate krunner (<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> or <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>), enter *Display* and what you are looking for should be one of the suggestions (the first one on my system).